# Find cube of individual element given by user. (Vue js)

Tags: loops, vue.js, vuejs2, cube

I want user to enter a number then it will find the cube of it. Also I have to show the cube of each individual element of the output.

For eg. user enters 3.
first output should be 27
then I want to show the cube of 2 and 7 individually.

Here's what I came up with...
https://jsfiddle.net/ods0621f/

```
<div id="app">
  <input v-model='mainNumber' placeholder='Enter a number.'>
  <button v-on:click="cube">Submit</button>
  <p>
    Cube of the number is: {{ mainNumber }} <br>
  </p>
  <p v-for="index in methods">
  {{ index }}
  </p>
</div>

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mainNumber: ''
  },
  methods: {
    cube: function(event){
    var allowedInput = /^[0-9]/;
    if (this.mainNumber.match(allowedInput)){
    this.mainNumber = this.mainNumber*this.mainNumber*this.mainNumber;
    var splitNumber = (""+this.mainNumber).split("");
    console.log(splitNumber[1]);

    }
    else
    {
    alert('Only digits are allowed.');
    }
    }
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close, although we needed to abstract some functionality such as the cubed algorithm, and to understand Numbers and Strings:

```
let calc = this.cubeInt(this.mainNumber);
let strToNum = calc.toString().split('').map(Number);
```

All out cubeInt does is cube the number.
strToNum: Converts our Number type into a String type, We split each character into an array, then we use the map function to Number - which will take the first argument being our String, and convert it to a Number.

(I added some template CSS to style the table)

```js
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  data: {
    mainNumber: null,
    result: null
  },
  methods: {
    cubeInt: function(int) {
     return int*int*int
    },
   cube: function(event){
      var allowedInput = /^[0-9]/;
      if (this.mainNumber.match(allowedInput)){
        let calc = this.cubeInt(this.mainNumber);
        let strToNum = calc.toString().split('').map(Number);
        this.result = strToNum
      } else {
      alert('Only digits are allowed.');
     }
    },
    }
})
```

```css
#customers {
  font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 50%;
  text-align: center;
}

#customers td, #customers th {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  padding: 8px;
}

#customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

#customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <input v-model='mainNumber' placeholder='Enter a number.'>
  <button v-on:click="cube">Submit</button>
  <p>
    Cube of the number is: {{ this.result }} <br>
  </p>
 <table id="customers">
 <tr v-for="row in 2" :key="item">
   <td v-for="item in result" v-text="row > 1 ? cubeInt(item) : item"></td>
 </tr>
 </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Can you please help me understand what you did with <td> tag.
-v-text="row > 1 ? cubeInt(item) : item"         (I don't quite understand this part.)

Comment: Sure what do you need me to elaborate on? EDIT: Cool okay, so thats a short-hand IF statement. All im doing is checking that if its the second row, run the cubeInt() on the item, otherwise just return the item. So without the function you would have the same value on both rows